# Docker remove root user from image at build time

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a simple **Dockerfile** that is based on **debian**

```
FROM debian

USER 1001
```

I build it

```
docker build -t no-root:1 .
```

I run it

```
docker run --name test -it no-root:1
```

Now I have a non-root shell

```
I have no name!@2ac786ca2265:/$
```

But, I can `exec` into the container from another shell with

```
docker exec -it --user 0 test bash
```

And I get a **root** shell

```
root@e043edec4585:/#
```

And run **root** commands...

Is it possible the remove the **root** user from the system at build time so `docker exec -it --user 0 test bash` will fail?

I tried deleting the `root` line from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. It did not help. I'm able to `docker exec -it --user 0 test bash` in.

So - is there a way?

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no. You can't prevent docker from creating a process as root (uid 0).

Answer (score 2):

Well it's simple enough to change users, something like the below which is an example I pinched off another site.

```
RUN useradd -c 'Node.js user' -m -d /home/node -s /bin/bash node
RUN chown -R node.node /src
USER node
ENV HOME /home/node
```

I don't recommend trying to delete the root user. The above should stop root from being used  on `docker exec`.

And alternative is to create a `.profile` in the root users home directory which logs into a different user instead but this'll only affect usage of exec where you're running `-it {container} bash` (aka, interactive shell)

Comment: Adding your lines didn't help. I'm still logged in as root. Just with the `/home/node` as my default home. Did I miss something?

Comment: Those were just an example, you're using a Debian image so look up how to create a new user on Debian

Comment: The user is created correctly and the default container starts with the `node` user. It's an `exec --user 0` from a new shell that allows root access.

Comment: Only people you trust should be accessing your docker socket. Restrict their permissions on their machines if you really have to I suppose. You cannot delete the root user without breaking your container though

Comment: `sudo passwd -l root` disables root login, don't know why I didn't suggest that before

Comment: Still no. I added `passwd -l root` to my Dockerfile. Was still able to `exec --user 0` in.

Comment: Can't be 100% sure that would work in the docker file, I'd put it in your entrypoint.sh. However I'm surprised `RUN sudo passwd -l root` didn't give some kind of result. Why don't you open a bash interface and play around with that command and the root user to see where you can get to?

Comment: I tried many options in an open shell. I'll keep trying and update of the results.